# Jquery select change on selected option

Tags: jquery

I want to catch the change event even when user click on currently selected option, simple
`$("select").change();` doesn't work in this case.

What is the solution?

EDIT:
I mean of course `change()`, sorry. It doesn't work either.

EDIT2:
The event must be fired even when user don't change currently selected option when clicking on select.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I mean `change` instead of `click`, sorry.

Comment: If a user clicks on a currently selected option, there is NO change to be fired.

Comment: So how can I achieve to be fired?

Comment: Can you give an example how this is going to be used ?

Comment: It will be select with couple action like mark selected as read or remove selected.

Comment: @methyl I've removed my solution...it makes sense that it doesn't work in all browsers. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it :

http://jsfiddle.net/78x9Q/4/

Just had to put it in a containing div and fire the click event on that .

Comment: And on Chrome nothing? Have you tried playing around with the numclicks variable?  maybe it doesn't see the first click.

Comment: Weird , If you remove the if statement it works fine in safari.

Comment: I think it's related to specific for Mac OS handling for selects.

Comment: does the work-around work in safari on mac ? if it does it's probably a chrome bug .

Comment: Doesn't work--try clicking the pulldown, and then clicking out of the list, which closes the pulldown, then next time clicking in the pulldown it thinks it's the second click.  Maybe works if you put a click reset on the 'blur' event? -- EDIT:  yeah, that seems to work.

Comment: Fiddle with blur: http://jsfiddle.net/78x9Q/106/ (also moved the id to the select, don't know why it was in the div)

Comment: Update--still doesn't work -- it is possible to mouse down, scroll, mouse up, to select a pulldown option.  this is only one click and thus messes up the click count.

Answer (score 3):

look for : `$("select").change();`

Comment: javascript is case sensitive, I think should be  $("select").change();

Answer (score 1):

Using option `.change` is the proper way to handle. `.click` on option is not support in all browsers.

<s>**Edit:**  below answer is based on Click which was asked initially. Use .change() which will be fired after the option is changed.</s>

Use $('option').click to capture click on options.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/78x9Q/2/)** here

Comment: For some weird reason, fiddle isn't working in IE 7. It worked on FF. And just the html alone is not brining up the dropdown.

Comment: Click on option is only supported by Firefox.

Comment: @KevinPeno True, At that time.. coz of messed up IE (uninstalling IE 8 and installing some IE in my PC) jsFiddle was allowing me to click on the drop down.. but yea it is true. Thanks for leaving a comment though. Updated answer.. well there is a better solution there too.

Answer (score -1):

`change` should work though there is nothing that click will not work. A simple [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vKdeD/4/)

[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKdeD/16/)